# Git-Flow Maven Plugin: hotfix branch

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-flow

I'm trying to create a hotfix version from within a Jenkinsfile using the [Git-Flow Maven Plugin](https://github.com/aleksandr-m/gitflow-maven-plugin).

After some initial success, I see now some strange behaviour.

I have the following *support* branch for stabilization: `support/release-3.x`

First I run the following Maven command:

```
mvn -e -B -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -DperformRelease=true gitflow:hotfix-start -DfromBranch=support/release-3.x -DhotfixVersion=3.4.0
```

This results in the following output:

```
[INFO] --- gitflow-maven-plugin:1.14.0:hotfix-start (default-cli) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Checking for uncommitted changes.
[INFO] Checking out 'support/release-3.x' branch.
[INFO] Fetching remote branch 'origin support/release-3.x'.
[INFO] Comparing local branch 'support/release-3.x' with remote 'origin/support/release-3.x'.
[INFO] Creating a new branch 'hotfix/support/release-3.x/3.4.0' from 'support/release-3.x' and checking it out.
[INFO] Updating version(s) to '3.4.0'.
[INFO] Committing changes.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] --------------------
```

As you can see, the plugin creates for some reason the branch `hotfix/support/release-3.x/3.4.0` instead of `hotfix/3.4.0`.

Afterwards the following command gets executed:

```
 mvn -e -B -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -DperformRelease=true gitflow:hotfix-finish -DhotfixVersion=3.4.0 -DpostHotfixGoals=deploy -e -B -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -DperformRelease=true -Dverbose=true
```

And this results in:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gitflow-maven-plugin:1.14.0:hotfix-finish (default-cli) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Checking for uncommitted changes.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.721 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-03T14:06:38+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.amashchenko.maven.plugin:gitflow-maven-plugin:1.14.0:hotfix-finish (default-cli) on project my-project: hotfix-finish: Hotfix branch with name 'hotfix/3.4.0' doesn't exist. Cannot finish hotfix. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.amashchenko.maven.plugin:gitflow-maven-plugin:1.14.0:hotfix-finish (default-cli) on project my-project: hotfix-finish
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: hotfix-finish
    at com.amashchenko.maven.plugin.gitflow.GitFlowHotfixFinishMojo.execute (GitFlowHotfixFinishMojo.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Hotfix branch with name 'hotfix/3.4.0' doesn't exist. Cannot finish hotfix.
    at com.amashchenko.maven.plugin.gitflow.GitFlowHotfixFinishMojo.execute (GitFlowHotfixFinishMojo.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

So in particular: `Hotfix branch with name 'hotfix/3.4.0' doesn't exist. Cannot finish hotfix.`

I also checked the [Maven Site documentation](https://aleksandr-m.github.io/gitflow-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) but couldn't find a parameter which could help.

What am I missing? How can this be solved?

**Update 1**

Same behaviour with gitflow-maven-plugin v1.15.0

**Update 2**

I tried now to manually rename the branch between `hotfix-start` and `hotfix-finish`.

Now I get the following error:

```
[INFO] --- gitflow-maven-plugin:1.15.0:hotfix-finish (default-cli) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Checking for uncommitted changes.
[INFO] Fetching remote branch 'origin hotfix/3.4.0'.
[WARNING] There were some problems fetching remote branch 'origin hotfix/3.4.0'. You can turn off remote branch fetching by setting the 'fetchRemote' parameter to false.
[INFO] Fetching remote branch 'origin develop'.
[WARNING] There were some problems fetching remote branch 'origin develop'. You can turn off remote branch fetching by setting the 'fetchRemote' parameter to false.
[INFO] Local branch 'master' doesn't exist. Trying to fetch and check it out from 'origin'.
[INFO] Fetching remote branch 'origin master'.
[INFO] Creating a new branch 'master' from 'origin/master' and checking it out.
[INFO] Fetching remote branch 'origin master'.
[INFO] Comparing local branch 'master' with remote 'origin/master'.
[INFO] Checking out 'hotfix/3.4.0' branch.
[INFO] Cleaning and testing the project.
[INFO] Checking out 'master' branch.
[INFO] Merging (--no-ff) 'hotfix/3.4.0' branch.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So hotfix-finish wants to merge `develop` and `master` instead of `support/release-3.x`

I guess I could set `fetchRemote` to `false` and `skipMergeDevBranch` and `skipMergeProdBranch` to `true`, but how can I merge back to the support branch?

Comment: As it currently looks like a bug to me, I filed an issue: https://github.com/aleksandr-m/gitflow-maven-plugin/issues/273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution as provider by aleksandr-m at https://github.com/aleksandr-m/gitflow-maven-plugin/issues/273:

In `hotfix-finish` use:

```
-DhotfixVersion=support/release-3.x/3.4.0
```